# How to reduce stream to single value if it size is 1 or to a default value if size > 1

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream with 0..n values. I want to:

- return value from stream if stream `count()` is `1`
- return `defaultValue` if stream `count()` is `0` or `> 1`

Code what I developed resolved this problem:

```
String result = Stream.of("someValue")
   .map(Optional::of)                  // reduce desn't accept `null`
   .reduce((a, b) -> Optional.empty()) // instead `null`
   .flatMap(Function.identity())       // unpack `Optional`
   .orElseGet(() -> "defaultValue");   // if returned our optional is empty,
                                       // so we can return default value
System.out.println(result);
```

But this hack with wraping stream values into `Optional` isn't easy to understand (in my opinion).
Do you know any other solution, which bases on stream API? How to write this in easy to read way?

Comment: can you add an example what you are trying to do?

Comment: Where do you get that stream from? If you're worrying about how easy your code is to understand (and that's a good thing to do) then why do you try to use a stream in the first place? If you originally have a collection or array then a simple tenary expression or if-else would be far simpler.

Comment: One would need a grouping by/counting which does not seem optimal either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to wrap elements into optionals at all? You can just do:

```
yourStream.limit(2).reduce((x, y) -> defaultValue).orElse(defaultValue)
```

`limit(2)`, so that you don't consume the whole stream. You just need to check at most 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more complex solution, use the following:

```
<T> T exactlyOneOr(Stream<T> stream, T defaultValue) {
  List<T> reference = new ArrayList<>(1);
  boolean exactlyOne = spliterator.tryAdvance(reference::add)
      && !spliterator.tryAdvance(x -> {});
  return exactlyOne ? reference.get(0) : defaultValue;
}
```

It is still performant and you shouldn't have much trouble understanding it. If you do, just ask for clarifications.

Comment: You don’t need an expensive `AtomicReference` here. E.g., you could use `ArrayList<T> reference = new ArrayList<>(1); return spliterator.tryAdvance(reference::add) && !spliterator.tryAdvance(x -> {})? reference.get(0): defaultValue;`

Comment: @Holger any holder is OK, even an array, but yeah, this answer is rough and could be a tad optimized.